# How to execute a function every two seconds in Java on Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, postdelayed

I'm trying to execute a chunk of Java code in my Android program every two seconds. My code currently looks like this:

```
       LinearLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 

            //Do stuff here

            } 
       }, 2000);
```

Unfortunately, this only runs once after two seconds and then never runs again. How could I get it to run every two seconds?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
   LinearLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 

        //Do stuff here

            // assuming LinearLayout is enclosing class
            LinearLayout.this.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        } 
   }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a loop.  Or you could look into [Alarms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can try a [timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

Here is another [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Enter your code which you want to execute every 2 second
        }
    }, 0, 2000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
```