# Dateformat not updated when the time is changed

Tags: android, date, android-activity, clock, simpledateformat

i am developing an android app where in i am displaying the date and time for the user on the main screen of my app. I am using the below code for it.

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd MMM yyyy");
        String strtDates = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        textviewfordate.setText(strtDates);

        clk = (DigitalClock)findViewById(R.id.digitalClock);
```

However, when the time is changed, the date doesnot get updated without refreshing the screen. For example when the time is 11:59:00 PM and when the time changes to 12:00:00 AM, the date will not be updated. It gets updated only when the screen is refreshed. I want the date to be changed automatically without refreshing the screen.

Not getting how to do it! Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you set a text to textview in `onCreate()`, it will **run only once when that method is called** and won't get updated everytime the time changes.

For your need, you have to use `handler` or `executor` or any other `thread` which runs for every user defined time, and you have to set the ***current time text to textview inside them***. So, that the text will be updated.

And also refer the following links, they will help you:

[Android run thread in service every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230606/android-run-thread-in-service-every-x-seconds)

[How to execute a function every two seconds in Java on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902600/how-to-execute-a-function-every-two-seconds-in-java-on-android)

[display data after every 10 seconds in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535733/display-data-after-every-10-seconds-in-android)